# model design for considering multiple work schedule with number

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to create convincing job hiring model. However I got stuck to show the conditions like 3 Full Time, 2 Part Time in a single job. For example, a company may post job for senior backend developer with job description and all where he may select both Full Time and Part Time work schedule. Probably he want to state how many Full Time and Part Time employer for that job. That is why I am using ManyToManyField for work schedule but I am not sure for the numbers of employeer for certain workschedule in an efficient manner.

Here is the model design that I have designed for now

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)


class WorkSchedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)


class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)


class Job(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, related_name='jobs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='jobs')
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    position = models.ManyToManyField(
        Position, related_name='jobs', blank=False, null=False)
    work_schedule = models.ManyToManyField(
        WorkSchedule, related_name='jobs', blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what do you need to achieve? Your description is not very clear. Maybe provide some examples of the output you want. Thanks

Comment: I am saying what If I want data as following for user to post Job title - Senior Python Developer
company - company name
city - Kathmandu
work schedule - 3 Full Time, 2 Part Time

look at the work schedule type

Comment: The way now the model is designed, a job poster can post multiple work schedule for a single job. Like if he/she wants both full time and part time employees, he can 
select both option as it is ManyToMany Field but he/she cannot specify how many Full Time employees and Part Time employees for that job he/she wants to post